# Iterate State Monad and Collect Results in Sequence with Good Performance

Tags: performance, haskell, vector, state-monad

I implemented the following function:

```hs
iterateState :: Int -> (a -> State s a) -> (a -> State s [a])
iterateState 0 f a = return []
iterateState n f a = do
    b <- f a
    xs <- iterateState (n - 1) f b
    return $ b : xs
```

My primary use case is for `a = Double`. It works, but it is very slow. It allocates 528MB of heap space to produce a list of 1M `Double` values and spends most of its time doing garbage collection.

I have experimented with implementations that work on the type `s -> (a, s)` directly as well as with various strictness annotations. I was able to reduce the heap allocation somewhat, but not even close to what one would expect from a reasonable implementation. I suspect that the resulting `([a], s)` being a combination of something to be consumed lazily (`[a]`) and something whose WHNF forces the entire computation (`s`) makes optimization difficult for GHC.

Assuming that the iterative nature of lists would be unsuitable for this situation, I turned to the `vector` package. To my delight, it already contains

```hs
iterateNM :: (Monad m, Unbox a) => Int -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m (Vector a)
```

Unfortunately, this is only slightly faster than my list implementation, still allocating 328MB of heap space. I assumed that this is because it uses `unstreamM`, whose description reads

> Load monadic stream bundle into a newly allocated vector. This function goes through a list, so prefer using unstream, unless you need to be in a monad.

Looking at its behavior for the list monad, it is understandable that there is no efficient implementation for general monads. Luckily, I only need the state monad, and I found another function that *almost* fits the signature of the state monad.

```hs
unfoldrExactN :: Unbox a => Int -> (b -> (a, b)) -> b -> Vector a
```

This function is blazingly fast and performs no excess heap allocation beyond the 8MB needed to hold the resulting unboxed vector of 1M `Double` values. Unfortunately, it does not return the final state at the end of the computation, so it cannot be wrapped in the `State` type.

I looked at the implementation of `unfoldrExactN` to see if I could adjust it to expose the final state at the end of the computation. Unfortunately, this seems to be difficult, as the stream constructed by

```hs
unfoldrExactN :: Monad m => Int -> (s -> (a, s)) -> s -> Stream m a
```

which is eventually expanded into a vector by `unstream` has already forgotten the state type `s`.

I imagine I could circumvent the entire `Stream` infrastructure and implement `iterateState` directly on mutable vectors in the `ST` monad (similarly to how `unstream` expands a stream into a vector). However, I would lose all the benefits of stream fusion, as well as turning a computation that is easily expressed as a pure function into imperative low-level mush just for performance reasons. This is particularly frustrating while knowing that the existing `unfoldrExactN` already calculates all the values I want, but I have no access to them.

Is there a better way?

Can this function be implemented in a purely functional way with reasonable performance and no excess heap allocations? Preferably in a way that ties into the `vector` package and its stream fusion infrastructure.

Comment: Can't you use unfoldrExactNM and make m as (s,) ?

Comment: Can you demand `Unbox s`? If so, one idea might be to use `unfoldrExactN` to produce a vector of `(a, s)`s. A `Vector (a,s)` turns out to be essentially a `(Vector a, Vector s)`, so you can cheaply get your `Vector a` and return the last element (or the incoming state, if generating 0 elements) of the `Vector s`.

Comment: @pedrofurla I am not entirely sure what you mean. If you are talking about the `Monoid a => Monad ((,) a)` instance, my `s` is not a monoid and combining it that way makes no sense either. Also, I believe that all of the monadic functions of the `vector` package go through `unstreamM` and suffer from the same performance problems.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's a good idea. My `s` is an RNG, so it might be possible to unbox it, but I have no experience with that. However, it would be kind of unfortunate to jump through additional hoops and to place all these restrictions on my function just so it can replicate a value a million times when it is really only needed once. :/.

Comment: Which `State` are you using?

Comment: @Carl I am using `Control.Monad.State.Lazy`, but I have also tried `Control.Monad.State.Strict` as well as the type `s -> (a, s)` with various strictness annotations. There were some differences, but I was unable to prevent the implementation from spending most of its time doing GC on boxed values and/or thunks with any of the state types I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program has 12MB max residency on my computer when compiled with optimizations:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable

iterateNState :: Unbox a => Int -> (a -> s -> (s, a)) -> (a -> s -> (s, Vector a))
iterateNState n f a0 s0 = createT (unsafeNew n >>= go 0 a0 s0) where
    go i a s arr
        | i >= n = pure (s, arr)
        | otherwise = do
            unsafeWrite arr i a
            case f a s of
                (s', a') -> go (i+1) a' s' arr

main = id
    . print
    . Data.Vector.Unboxed.sum
    . snd
    $ iterateNState 1000000 (\a s -> (s+1, a+s :: Int)) 0 0
```

(It continues to have a nice low residency even when the final two `0`s are read from input dynamically.)

Comment: Criterion tells me that this example runs in 10.5ms and allocates 96MB with 10MB total memory in use. Changing `go i a s arr` to `go i !a s arr` makes it run in 1.1ms and allocates 8MB with the same total memory usage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The code runs as fast as `unfoldrExactN` while also returning the final state, so I am happy. I will wait a few days to see if there is an implementation that is more pure/declarative/compositional/fusable and if not, accept your answer.

Comment: @Jules Are you compiling with `-O2` in your 10.5ms/96MB example?

Comment: I compiled with `-O2 -fllvm`. I just tried again without `-fllvm`, which gave me 9.7ms/96MB. This is using `ghc 8.10.5`.

Comment: @Jules Odd. I'm using 8.10.4 here, and with `-O2` I get negligible time (0.00s) and 12MB maxresident, as reported in the answer, according to `/usr/bin/time`.

Comment: I just tested it again with 8.10.4 and I'm getting the same behavior. Our results on residence agree, maybe you are just getting <10ms and it gets truncated to 0.00s by `time`? Would be interesting to know if you see a difference between `a` and `!a` with a repeated and/or longer test.

Comment: @Jules Ahhh, I misread your original comment. My eyes glazed over the 10MB and I saw only "96MB total memory in use", which is what I was objecting to. Great, we seem to be in agreement about performance, then!